# How do I write R like for-loops in Python with indexing and many ifelse statements in pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, r, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I have a specific for loop which I want to translate into Python but realized that Python does not use indexing. I know how to use enumerate() and simpler for loops where there is no deeper purpose with the for loop.

This time, I have a grouped dataframe which needs to iterate from index `2:N` and thereby skipping 1st index in R => 0th index in Python.

Basically, I want to look for product number and store number occuring in row `i` to see if it matches row `i-1` and then execute some `ifelse` statements with values occurring in row `i` and `i-1` from columns in the dataframe.

**For loop in R using data.table `set()` that I want to translate into Python**

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) set(df, i, "col_A", 
                         ifelse(df$col_B[i]==df$col_B[i-1] & df$col_C[i]==df$col_C[i-1],
                                0, 
                                1
                                )
                         )
```

Comment: First try to rerwite the same with no for-loops. Pandas, numpy and R are all vectorized. You have too much ifelse conditions to the point that one is unable to follow

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll edit into a shorter version.

Comment: could you try running `df[, new := +(col_B == shift(col_B) & col_C == shift(col_C)][]` and check whether the column named `new` gives the results you want

Comment: Yes, it returns a logical column in R. But I am interested in likewise but for Python.

Comment: I understand. The thing is you do not need the for- loop. eg you could do `df['new'] = df.col_B == df.col_B.shift() & df.col_C == df.col_C.shift()` You see. No for loops

Comment: That actually solved alot except one thing - starting from 2:N. If you provide that then you will probably solve it for me! =)

Comment: Whtat do you mean by starting from 2:N? the code works on the whole dataframe. No need of looping through the indices. If this does not help, you will have to post data, and include the results you want from the data. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see how to ask a question

Comment: Yes but starting from index 2 instead of 1 or clearly put starting from index 1 in python instead of 0.

Comment: I see. Thats because it should be NA. you can drop the first row, or change the first value to NA. now google on how to do that WITHOUT FOR LOOPS. try to avoid as much as you can the for-loops unless its recursive or unavoidable. Always remember there is a vectorized way to do something,

Comment: `df.new[0] = float('nan')`

Comment: Thank you, I will take your advice and gladly train more on that. I am glad to provide that you solved my problem if you choose to write an answer.